# How should I approach making server-side software for an Android application?

Tags: android, frontend, backend

In the past I have used Python for backend stuff along with Django for frontend stuff, but I don't know how well those two work with Android.

Can anyone recommend a good way to go about making server-side software that works well with Android?

Please take into account that I also want a web application as a frontend, so the backend should work with both the web app and the Android app.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might start by developing an HTTP API using Django, tornado, cherrypy, or any other web framework.  This API may then be used by both your web frontend and your Android application.

In general, separating out the API from the application serves to clean up the code and make future changes easier.  In this case, it also makes it easy for you to have multiple frontends without having to replicate the backend functionality.

If it's possible to create a web application version of your project, consider that it may be easiest just to create a version of that application which is formatted for the android screen, and allow Android users to use the same web application with appropriate styling.